# How to change chrome header color in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

The default color for this header at the top with the link URL is blue, does anyone know how to change the color of it ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this meta tag between "head" tag in index.html file.

```HTML
<meta name="theme-color" content="#393557">
```

It will change your mobile browser's top menu color.

Comment: can you post the tag here ?

Comment: <meta name="theme-color" content="#393557">

Comment: how to change it based on app theme color? instead of hardcoding the color?

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi you could specify the theme in your meta tag. Or set it dynamically via dart:js. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474183/1399597

Answer (score 3):

You can set it for dark and light theme by adding following code to `web/index.html` file.

```HTML
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#FFFFFF">
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"  content="#000000">
```