# Flutter web status bar in iOS (Safari)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I try to change the status bar in the safari browser, I search it and it was a lot's question about it but none of them fixed my issue.
I tried [change-status-bar-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489458/how-to-change-status-bar-color-in-flutter) and [how-to-change-chrome-header-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317046/how-to-change-chrome-header-color-in-flutter-web).

[image]

This blue area is around iPhone's notches, and I want to change the color in the whole app.

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to change the value for `theme-color`. The default color you're seeing is defined in your `web/manifest.json` file.

You could also set it, for example to white for your light-theme and to black for your dark-theme, by adding following lines to your `web/index.html`:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#FFFFFF">
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"  content="#000000">
```

You could also change it dynamically via `dart:js` by adding a script to your `web/index.html`:

```html
<script>
  function setMetaThemeColor(color) {
      document.querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]').setAttribute("content", color);
    }
</script>
```

Then call it via `dart:js`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:js' as js;

extension ColorString on Color {
  String toHexString() {
    return '#${(value & 0xFFFFFF).toRadixString(16).padLeft(6, '0').toUpperCase()}';
  }
}

void setMetaThemeColor(Color color) {
  js.context.callMethod("setMetaThemeColor", [color.toHexString()]);
}
```

Comment: should be accepted. manifest.json didn't work for me (don't know why) but index.html config worked perfectly. Don't forget to clear safari cache or use private navigation to see changes quickly

Comment: Thanks this works. Any idea if it is possible to put this on Dart code instead?

Answer (score 3):

#### Flutter 3.13.0

Status bar color can be changed based on `SystemUiOverlayStyle`.

Check out Proposal for more information: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123365

Check out Pull Request for more information: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/40599

---

1. **Using `AppBar` widget:**

   ```dart
   Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red),
     ),
   )
   ```

---

2. **Using `AnnotatedRegion`:**

   ```dart
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
       value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red),
       child: ...,
     );
   }
   ```

---

3. **Call `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` from your code:**

   ```dart
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red));
   ```

---

4. **Call `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` inside build method:**

   ```dart
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red));

     return ...;
   }
   ```

#### Below Flutter 3.13.0

---

1. **Using `MaterialApp.color` property:**

   ```dart
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return const MaterialApp(
       color: Colors.red,
       home: ...,
     );
   }
   ```

---

2. **Using `MaterialApp.theme.primaryColor` property:**

   ```dart
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.red),
       home: ...,
     );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the below code:

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.red,
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I checked it before and it's not working. it worked in the android browser but not in Safari.

Comment: can you make me understand the safari aspect very well? i try that code on ios n is working